# Async method parallel execution

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to execute some methods in parallel using async methods but these methods are not executing parallel.

Here is my code.

```
public class MyServiceAsync
{
    private long a = 10000;
    public async Task GetData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        var task1 = Method1();
        Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        var task2 = Method2();
        Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        var task3 = Method3();
        Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        await task1;
        await task2;
        await task3;
        Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }

    public async Task Method1()
    {
        for (long i = 0; i < a * a; i++)
        {

        }
    }
    public async Task Method2()
    {
        for (long i = 0; i < a * a; i++)
        {

        }
    }
    public async Task Method3()
    {
        for (long i = 0; i < a * a; i++)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And I am executing the methods.

```
MyServiceAsync service1 = new MyServiceAsync();
service1.GetData().Wait();
```

The method2 is not executing until the method1 is finished.

Thanks
Imrankhan

Comment: how about `await` or `Task.Yield` in your Methods?

Comment: your methods do not include any asynchronicity so they do not need to be marked as `async`. you can call them in `Task.Run`.

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous in this code. `async` doesn't make something run asynchronously, it's just syntactic sugar that allows the use of `await` to *await* an already executing asynchronous operation to complete without blocking. There's are no such operations in this code. All methods will execute synchronously, one after the other, at the moment they are invoked

Comment: To run each of those methods in a separate task use `Task.Run`. If you want to process a lot of data use PLINQ or `Parallel.For/ForEach`. 10K iterations of integer multiplication isn't enough to show any benefit from parallelization though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);` to get them to execute in parallel.

At the moment, you are still executing the tasks in a serial fashion by awaiting each one individually.

**Edit:**

To demonstrate what Panagiotis means about "there are no tasks in this code":

**Without tasks:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mainTask = MainAsync(args);
        mainTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var task1 = Method1();
        var task2 = Method2();
        var task3 = Method3();

        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public static async Task<long> Method1()
    {
        var returnValue = 0l;
        for (long i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Method 1 : {i}");
            returnValue += i;
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(returnValue);
    }

    public static async Task<long> Method2()
    {
        var returnValue = 0l;
        for (long i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Method 2 : {i}");
            returnValue += i;
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(returnValue);
    }

    public static async Task<long> Method3()
    {
        var returnValue = 0l;
        for (long i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Method 3 : {i}");
            returnValue += i;
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(returnValue);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Method 1 : 0
Method 1 : 1
Method 1 : 2
Method 1 : 3
Method 1 : 4
Method 2 : 0
Method 2 : 1
Method 2 : 2
Method 2 : 3
Method 2 : 4
Method 3 : 0
Method 3 : 1
Method 3 : 2
Method 3 : 3
Method 3 : 4
```

**With tasks (i.e. properly await a real asynchronous action):**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mainTask = MainAsync(args);
        mainTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var task1 = Method1();
        var task2 = Method2();
        var task3 = Method3();

        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public static async Task<long> Method1()
    {
        var returnValue = 0l;
        for (long i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Method 1 : {i}");
            returnValue += i;
            await Task.Delay(1);
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(returnValue);
    }

    public static async Task<long> Method2()
    {
        var returnValue = 0l;
        for (long i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Method 2 : {i}");
            returnValue += i;
            await Task.Delay(1);
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(returnValue);
    }

    public static async Task<long> Method3()
    {
        var returnValue = 0l;
        for (long i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Method 3 : {i}");
            returnValue += i;
            await Task.Delay(1);
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(returnValue);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
    Method 1 : 0
    Method 2 : 0
    Method 1 : 1
    Method 3 : 0
    Method 3 : 1
    Method 1 : 2
    Method 2 : 1
    Method 3 : 2
    Method 1 : 3
    Method 2 : 2
    Method 2 : 3
    Method 1 : 4
    Method 3 : 3
    Method 3 : 4
    Method 2 : 4
```

Comment: Fair point. I did make the assumption that the OP was implying there were tasks being executed in the blank loop sections. If there are tasks, my code works for parallel execution.